# Creating search form with Bootstrap and Perlfect

Tags: search, bootstrap, perl

I have built a website using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta. I want to add the ability to search the site. I am attempting to use a script called [Perlfect Search 3.37](http://www.perlfect.com/freescripts/search/). Though it hasn't been updated in a while it has worked great on another site I have.

My problem is how to mesh the code for Bootstrap and Perlfect two together:

Bootstrap code:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light submit2 my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Perlfect code [details on the parameters can be found [on this site]](http://www.perlfect.com/freescripts/search/readme.shtml):

```
<form method="get" action="/cgi-bin/perlfect/search/search.pl">
  <input type="hidden" name="p" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
  <input type="hidden" name="include" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="exclude" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="penalty" value="0">
  <select name="mode">
    <option value="all">Match ALL words</option>
    <option value="any">Match ANY word</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="q"><input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I don't really care to use the "match" option.

I had tried the following but it doesn't return any results for any number of search terms that are available.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="/cgi-bin/perlfect/search/search.pl">
  <input type="hidden" name="p" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
  <input type="hidden" name="include" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="exclude" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="penalty" value="0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light submit2 my-2 my-sm-0" type="text" name="q" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What does the code you posted with the form for the search box have to do with the results returned?

Comment: I'm not asking so much about the results as I am about combining the two codes so that it works as it should.

Comment: Do any of those work?   It sounds like none of them do.   If that is the case, it is likely a problem of how your search index is built.

Comment: The Perlfect code works just fine. As I have said previously, I am trying to combine the two, minus the the "match" option, so it will fit the current design.

Comment: Have you tried adding `<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="all">`?

Comment: It looks like you put the `name="q"` on the button rather than on the text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else has the same type problem, here is the solution I used:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="/cgi-bin/perlfect/search/search.pl">
  <input type="hidden" name="p" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
  <input type="hidden" name="include" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="exclude" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="penalty" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="all">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-light submit2 my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```